# Combine Multiple named ranges if name contains

Tags: google-sheets

I'm not sure of the best way of going about this so any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have a spreadsheet containing multiple sheets which contain named ranges. I want to combine all these ranges in another sheet. I know I can return a single range using:

`=ARRAYFORMULA(Sheet1!list)`

But I'm not sure how to combine the values from sheet2, 3 etc where they also contain a named range containing "list". I also need the formula to be flexible enough so that if additional sheets are added they are also factored in.

Ideally I would want them returned in a long list as the named ranges will be the same size in terms of column width but will vary in rows.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

Use the array notation. Assuming that the names of the named ranges are list1, list2, and list3 and they belong to Sheet1, Sheet2 and Sheet3 respectively, and they have the same number of columns, then the formula to use is:

```
={Sheet1!list1;Sheet2!list2;Sheet3!list3}
```